# Hide labels in TabNavigator - ReactNavigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

How do I hide the labels in `TabNavigator` and show only `icons`? If I do the following:

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen:MainHome,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "Home",  //Tried to hide this for next tab Search.
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => <View><MaterialIcons name="home"/></View>
      })
  },
  Search: {
    screen:TestComp1,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      //If no title it shows the name as Search.
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => <View><MaterialIcons name="accessibility"/></View>
    })

  }
}, { 

   tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

   tabBarOptions: {
    showIcon: true,
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',  //Not working for icons.
    inactiveBackgroundColor: 'green', // Not working at all.
    style: {backgroundColor: '#3498DB', height: 60, padding:0, margin:0}
  }
});
```

If I remove `title` from the `navigationOptions` it shows the name of the Tab (`Home` or `Search`). I want to only show the icons and change the color of the active `icon`. `activeTintColor` not working for icons.

Comment: How to conditionally hide and show label? Say label should be shown only if tab is active

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TabNavigator` has `showLabel` prop that you can set. For more info please refer to [docs for v1](https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html#tabbaroptions-for-tabbarbottom-default-tab-bar-on-ios) or [docs for v2](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-navigator.html#tabbaroptions-for-tabbarbottom-default-tab-bar-on-ios).

> **showIcon** - whether to show icon for tab, default is false
>
> **showLabel** - whether to show label for tab, default is true

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of showing Icon without Label.

```
tabBarOptions: {
  showLabel: false,
  showIcon: true,
  tintColor: '#333',
  activeTintColor: '#aaa',
}
```

I defined tintColor and activeTintColor for changing active tab's label color.for changing active tab's icon color you need to define tabBarIcon for each tab and pass tintColor to it. for example if you have a search tab you can do it like this:

```
Search: {
  screen: SearchScreen,
  navigationOptions:{
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="ios-search" style={{color:tintColor}} />
    )
  }
},
```